# Excel charts flickering/moving on screen

Tags: excel, charts, vba

We have a spreadsheet with a series of chart sheets that contain simple line graphs. On one user's device, they are having issues with these charts moving around the screen constantly every second or so, essentially bouncing back and forth between two points. Creating a new chart and sending it to its own sheet results in the same issue, even on a new spreadsheet. The same spreadsheet works fine on every other device we've tried it on.

User has Excel 2013.

What I tried:

- Office Quick Repair
- Office Full Repair
- Office Uninstall, reboot, fresh install
- Update graphics drivers
- Roll back updates
- Disabled all add-ins
- Disabled protected view (on a networked drive)
- Copied to local device
- Deleted Excel .xlb file

This issue has only cropped up within the last few days. No notable updates were performed during this time. Has anyone else ever run into something like this? Stumped :/

Comment: question more suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I copied it over there with a reference back to this...

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue through some further debugging. We ended up having a faulty printer driver installed on the PC. By switching to a different default printer, Excel no longer displayed the flickering. Updating to a new printer driver was a long term fix.

Comment: I just had this issue with Office 2019. In my case, the default printer had changed to one that was offline. This answer just saved me hours of time.